# How to position icon on the right side of ion-card-header?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

This question may be a little stupid but I am not that familiar with CSS and googling the problem didnt get the desired result.

So I have this `ion-card-header`:

This is the code:

```
<ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>{{enActivity.customer}}</ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-title>{{enActivity.startTime | date :'HH:mm'}}</ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-title>Aktivitäten: {{enActivity.activities.length}}</ion-card-title>

      <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon> 
</ion-card-header>
```

I would like to place the last item, the `ion-icon` on the right sideof the card-header. How do I achieve this? I am a little confused.

In the picture, I would like to place the icon in the marked position.

This is what I have tried so far

```
ion-icon {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Give it a shot with [position: 'absolute'](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) and edit your question with what you've tried please

Comment: I'm not sure i understood your question, you want to maintain the chevron on the same line, but pullig it on the right. Is it correct?

Comment: Thanks for every answer! The problem was solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-title>{{enActivity.customer}}</ion-card-title>
  <ion-card-title>{{enActivity.startTime | date :'HH:mm'}}</ion-card-title>
  <ion-card-title>Aktivitäten: {{enActivity.activities.length}}</ion-card-title>

  <ion-icon className="center-right" name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
```

```
ion-card-header { position: relative }
.center-right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: yeah, this works so far. But if I make the icon bigger, it is not centered anymore but goes more to the bottom. Any ideas on this?

Comment: can you post an image?

Comment: add `transform: translateY(-50%);` to .center-right.
I edited the answer, you can copy from it.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ion-card{
Flex-direction: column;
}

ion-icon{
Margin:10px;
 }
```

Comment: yeah tried. check out my edited question and the new picture, I think I havent explained my situation properly

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In general, it's useful if you can explain what your solution is doing so that the author can understand what fixes their issue.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the content and the icon into two Sections or Div's and use display flex

```css
.ion-card-header {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
     }
```

Comment: perfect answer. you can change the value of the property "justify-content" to left or start or end or right to align the items right or left side of the header

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ion-card-header { position: relative }

ion-icon{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

Comment: Now the icon disappeared

Comment: Did you set your ion-card-header to ```position: relative```?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>{{enActivity.customer}}</ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-title>{{enActivity.startTime | date :'HH:mm'}}</ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-title>Aktivitäten: {{enActivity.activities.length}}</ion-card-title>

      <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" slot="end"></ion-icon> 
</ion-card-header>

 hope this will work
```